# MemoryStream is null when creating a new Bitmap from Stream

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a Bitmap from a stream that has a PDF document saved with-in the stream, but I keep getting argument null exception. The MS is not null and it is positioned at 0. So I'm lost as to what else to do.

I'm testing the functionality by using a windows forms application sandbox but I cannot get the memory stream to save to a Bitmap.

Can someone point out to me where I'm going wrong?

```
   private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //4355,4373

    IElevation elev = await ElevationManager.GetElevationAsync(4355);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc =
      await (await AlumCloudPlans.Manager.GetLabelsAsync(elev)).GetPDF(new SheetInfo(/*settings for PDF, Img printing is different*/3, 10, 240, 95, 780, 1000));

    System.IO.Stream ms = new MemoryStream();

    pdfDoc.Save(ms, false);
    ms.Position = 0;

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms); <---------(Error right here, says argument null)

    this.AutoScroll = true;
    this.pictureBox1.Image = bm;
    this.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(bm.Width, (bm.Height + 50) / 2);
    this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(bm.Width, bm.Height + 5);
}
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Why do people think pdf is an image format? It _isn't_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to open stream containing a PDF document, Bitmap constructor is expecting image data. PDFSharp can only create PDF document, but can't render it to image.

To render PDF document to bitmap, you have to use other libraries, e.g. [lib-pdf](http://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/), [mupdf-converter](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf-converter/) or .NET wrapper for Ghostscript.

Comment: Why do you have to be so ugly this early in the morning! ;) Can i just display the pdf in the windows form picture box?